# Vega or Vega Lite in Deneb generates the following error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'marktype')"

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I´ve run in the problem in Vega and Vega Lite that I couldn´t generate a signal that needs a field from data.

Example:

```
    {
      "name": "summeSignal",
      "update": "data('dataset')[0]['row']"
    }
```

The same happend if I tried to calculate values in marks or signals without using a defined signal.

I tried reducing the datasets, putting the signal block on other positions in the json in the hope that this maybe a parsing problem and I tried to acces data that isn´t ready yet.

That sadly did nothing for me.

EDIT:

I found two workarounds that helped.

1. adding a value to the dataset provided by powerBi:
   {"name": "dataset", "values": {"category": "test"}}

But that didn´t allways do the trick.

2. trigger the update with a timer event:
   {
   "name": "signal",
   "init": "0",
   "on": [
   {
   "events": [
   {
   "type": "timer",
   "throttle": 500
   }
   ],
   "update": "data('dataset')[0]['row']"
   }
   ]
   }

If there is a trigger for a data refresh or change that could be a more elegant solution, but I didn´t found any.

Comment: Please post a full spec and your desired outcome.

Comment: I ran in this problem in several ways. Already talked with Daniel Marsh-Patrick about it. It seems like this is a timing bug in Vega that tries to generate the Signal when the dataset isn't ready.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please post a full spec and your desired outcome so someone can help.

Comment: Typing on a smartphone resulted in a premature sending.

There seems to be a timing issue that can occure and lead to this problem. It is already a bug on github, that may be passed on to the Vega engine. Daniel Marsh-Patrick wanted to check this.

I was hoping, that there is a data refresh event I could trigger in deneb instead of running a timer to fix this problem.

Comment: If Daniel is looking at it already, you're in safe hands. I still don't fully understand the issue but will look on GitHub.

Comment: I ran in this problem with the solution you provided for making all scales the same.

It is not a problem that happens everytime. But it occured on some instances where I wanted to use data from a caluclated dataset in a signal.

Comment: I have also encountered this now and raised an issue.

Comment: One of the workarounds should help for the moment.